# What is the best way to connect physical IOs (from sensors or whatever), to a twincat 3 program that uses OOP?

Tags: twincat, plc4x, beckhof

I am trying to create a program that controls a fish tank. Oxygen, tempaerature, water level, and pump controls. But I am unsure of How to connec the physical inputs from the sensors to the variables of a function block, as it cant be done directly because the FB is used as a base by different objects. For example, FB_Sensor if I have 3 sensors then I cant link a physical input to a variable in FB_Sensor. So, what is the best way to do it?

I thought about creating a GVL that contains a list of variables that are lnked to the physical connections. Then use a method "Update_Values" which takes in the values from the GVL as inputs and updates the value of the varibales within the object i.e. Oxygen_Sensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function blocks, declare addresses this way :

```
input AT %I*: BIT;
output AT %Q*: BIT;
```

The type can be anything (including structures), I used BIT just as an example.

This tells the compiler "each instance of the function block will have its own mapped hardware addresses, but these addresses are not defined here". Of course, if you were to type in real addresses, all instances of the FB would refer to the same addresses, which is not what you want.

You can then declare several instances of your function block, and the I/O mapping UI of your IDE will show the variables of each instance as distinct mapping sources/targets.

I would strongly recommend doing this rather than having a global variables list along with code to copy values.

Comment: It gets a little "annoying", if you can call it that, if you are not using TwinCAT visualsation for UI. For using .Net you need to map all the variables via their full name, and if you don't first create a mapper of some sort that would display all the variables of the target, it gets quite annoying writting Main.fbInstance.VariableStruct.InputVar. In my case i prefer creating an IO struct so that I have an easier way of creating variables in my UI (I have quite a lot of inputs and outputs that are mapped to UI so it works for me). My case is a little different but just wanted to share it.

Comment: On our end, the HMI back-end works over OPC-UA, variables are part of a symbol configuration, and HMIs work on relative paths of variables (no hard-coded path). We have lots of visualizations that browse the variable tree to produce entirely generic views (quite a bit of scripting to achieve that, of course, but it is almost entirely generic and reusable).  We can create an HMI project from reusable views.  We therefore have very little to map. Mapping the "%I*" and "%Q*" variables is much, much more of a burden (but still not that bad).